# manifest merger failed-appcomponentfactory

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, androidx

i am trying to add **firebase** to my project but before adding this line implementation `'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'`  in dependencies the app was working fine but when i add this error is showing like this :

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0]
>
> AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-29:19 to override.

i have also tried the sugestion but it is not working for me